# Getting the following error (TypeError: undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'props.route.params.contactId))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I am getting a TypeError in the following peace of code: `if (typeof props.route.params != "undefined") {`

I am trying to check the existence of `props.route.params` and if it exist I am trying to fetch and filter data from redux.

In JS `props.route.params` would not fire a TypeError, but it is not working here, is there a workaround?

```
  const EditContactScreen = props => {
  let contactId, editedContact;

  const [nameDropdown, setNameDropdown] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState();

  const { navigation } = props;

  if (typeof props.route.params != "undifined") {
    contactId = props.route.params.contactId;
    editedContact = useSelector(state => {
      for(let i = 0; i  < state.contacts.length; i++){
        if(contactId === state.contacts[i].id){
          return state.contacts[i];
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I misspelled 'undefined' in the following line `typeof props.route.params != "undifined"`. Corrected it and worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const EditContactScreen = props => {
  let contactId, editedContact;

  const [nameDropdown, setNameDropdown] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState();

  const { navigation } = props;

  if ('contactId' in props.route.params) {
    contactId = props.match.contactId;
    editedContact = useSelector(state => {
      for(let i = 0; i  < state.contacts.length; i++){
        if(contactId === state.contacts[i].id){
          return state.contacts[i];
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

This should work

Comment: 'match' is not in my code, its 'route'. Yes, I know it holds 'param'. Trying to check if 'props.route.params' exists and if it does I want to enter the if statement

Comment: I am sorry about it, though it's about the router, so of course then ( 'params' in props.route) or ('contactId' in props.route.params) should do the work